# How to know in which form control exist

Tags: c#, forms

I have build 2 customized control.Control A and Control B

These controls are placed in more than 1 forms.

Let Suppose From A and Form B

Now let suppose user click the Control A in Form A.And this control click event is invoked.

Now how it would be identified that control A is located in  Form A.

So that I can change the specific attribute of Control B of Form A.

Comment: Would you please provide us with much details so we can provide you with better answers ...

Comment: Are you working on a windows forms based application ?? Why and where outside the form where the A & B controls reside do you want to handle the event of A ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Handle Control A 's event inside each form ..

Comment: But i have to handle these events every where they are using.

Comment: @Zain: With the details level you are providing, I am unable to provide you with a better solution ..

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Control.Parent` recursively. Also you can use `Control.TopLevelControl` if you don't have nested forms. Then you need to recursively walk `Controls` properties to find your second control.

But more proper solution of your task is to create a property in the first control and set it to the second control and use it in the event handler.

Comment: But these are customized control so there parent control will be customized control it self not the form in which they are located.

Comment: Parent of the control cannot be the control itself even if the control is customized but anyway I've used the word "recursively" for a purpose.

Answer (score 0):

What version of C# are you using? If you're using a relatively new version and are using Windows Presentation Foundation (WPF), you can do something like this:

```
private void ControlA_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    ((Grid)((ControlA)sender).Parent).Children
    // The above line is INCOMPLETE, you need to select the right child, but
    // you're at least in the right grid; The rest is up to you (depends on
    // the setup of your program);
}
```

There is another 'hack' option you can use, which is by far the easiest. You can use a controls 'tag' property to store whatever you like, so for example a pointer to ControlB.

```
ControlA a = new ControlA();
ControlB b = new ControlB();
a.Tag = b;
```

**Note** that this is a hack, and the proper way is to create such a field / variable on the custom control yourself. It's more or less a demo of how it could work.

*The answer of Akram Shahda is only an option if your forms are not dynamically created, since then you can predefine all actions. Nevertheless I wouldn't go that way.*